# Download ALL Folders, SubFolders, and Files using Wget

Tags: wget

I have been using Wget, and I have run across an issue.
I have a site,that has several folders and subfolders within the site.
I need to download all of the contents within each folder and subfolder.
I have tried several methods using Wget, and when i check the completion, all I can see in the folders are an "index" file.  I can click on the index file, and it will take me to the files, but i need the actual files.

does anyone have a command for Wget that i have overlooked, or is there another program i could use to get all of this information?

site example:

www.mysite.com/Pictures/
within the Pictures DIr, there are several folders.....

www.mysite.com/Pictures/Accounting/

www.mysite.com/Pictures/Managers/North America/California/JoeUser.jpg

I need all files, folders, etc.....

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `wget`, specifically for [using it recursively](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html)?

Comment: There's also an article in the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) that seems relevant.

Answer (score 60):

I want to assume you've not tried this:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://www.mysite.com/Pictures/
```

or to retrieve the content, without downloading the "index.html" files:

```
wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://www.mysite.com/Pictures/
```

Reference: [Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with arbitrary files in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273776)

Comment: Thanks, I have run that command several times, but i did not let the command finish all the way to the end.  I got side tracked, and let the command actually finish, and it copied ALL Folders First, then it went back and copied ALL of the files into the folder.

Comment: just goes to show you, if i had patience, i would have had this done 2 weeks ago.... LOL.  :) thanks again.

Comment: @Horrid Henry, Congratulations!

Comment: I use the similar command but only getting an index.html file!

Answer (score 36):

I use `wget -rkpN -e robots=off http://www.example.com/`

`-r` means recursively

`-k` means convert links. So links on the webpage will be localhost instead of example.com/bla

`-p` means get all webpage resources so obtain images and javascript files to make website work 
properly.

`-N` is to retrieve timestamps so if local files are newer than files on remote website skip them.

`-e` is a flag option it needs to be there for the `robots=off` to work.

`robots=off` means ignore robots file.

I also had `-c` in this command so if they connection dropped if would continue where it left off from when i re-run the command. I figured `-N` would go well with `-c`

Comment: Could you add a couple of sentences to your answer to explain what these the parameter settings do?

Comment: sorry. sure ill add them now

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks.  So should -c be part of your command example or added optionally after an incomplete download?  Also, the -e is so that the command takes precedence over any that may be in .wgetrc?  And is that a typo for -r (recursive vs. reclusive)?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Yes `-e` will execute command as if it were a part of .wgetrc I added it there as `robots=off` did not seem to work without it there.

Comment: This one works, the adopted answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

wget -m -A * -pk -e robots=off www.mysite.com/
this will download all type of files locally and point to them from the html file
and it will ignore robots file