# download images and keep subfolders with Wget from a list

Tags: wget

I have a list of links in a file as follow:

```
  https://xxxxx.com/folder1/xxxx.jpg
  https://xxxxx.com/folder1/folder2/xxxx.jpg
```

https://xxxxx.com is a constant

I would like to download in my server all the files in their respective folders as followed:
i.e

```
 /folder1/xxxx.jpg
 /folder1/folder2/xxxx.jpg
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download ALL Folders, SubFolders, and Files using Wget](https://superuser.com/questions/655554/download-all-folders-subfolders-and-files-using-wget)

Comment: Not really duplicate. The website subfolder are not accessible in my case. I have a list of folder/subfolder/images as stated.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ wget -x -nH -i file_with_links
```

Comment: Brilliant. It works! Thanks.