# How to download all files in a folder with wget

Tags: wget

I need to download all files in a domain folder says `https://example.com/folder/subfolder`. The subfolder files dont have unique increment, means the file names are random string. I want to download all the files in the subfolder using wget or any other method. Please give details.

I tried the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/655554/download-all-folders-subfolders-and-files-using-wget).  It only download index.html file. I tried other option in that answer with --reject option, but it don't download anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download ALL Folders, SubFolders, and Files using Wget](https://superuser.com/questions/655554/download-all-folders-subfolders-and-files-using-wget)

Comment: I tried that, It only download index.html file. I tried other option in that answer with `--reject` option, but it don't download anything.

Comment: Does each index.html file have a list of all the files at each folder level? I would suggest using Powershell, to read that file to obtain the file names and create the urls to download.

Comment: Page contains `Load more` option and index file have lines till load more button link which don't has href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, `wget` only works with links that:

- Explicitly have an standard `href` attribute.
- Are present in a given HTML document (which is something the server generates, so every *technically* available file may not always be listed for `wget` to download).

Furthermore, you should probably look at any raw page source (e.g. in your browser).  If the page uses JavaScript, you may be out of luck, as `wget` does not process JavaScript.

If a link is listed in the raw HTML, but without a standard `href` attribute, you can still parse the page for links, just not with `wget`. You would likely need to write your own script with something like Windows PowerShell or [Python](https://www.python.org/) (possibly with [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)) and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

---

*Note that in some rare cases, if the links are entirely generated by JavaScript, you might even need [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to save a fully rendered page before processing it for file links. Python has a [Selenium module](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and I have personally had good luck with the stand-alone "Marmaduke" builds (zip files) of [Ungoogled Chromium from Woolyss](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) for browser automation.*